# Factoring a polynomial over real numbers (no real roots)

Tags: polynomials

Polynomial is:
$$4x^4+2x+\frac{15}{16}$$
I know that the degree of the highest irreducible polynomial over reals is 2, so it should be possible to factor this polynomial into two second degree polynomials?

Comment: Yes, this is always possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOLG, let $4x^4+2x+15/16=(2x^2+ax+b)(2x^2+cx+d)$ be the disired factoring, then 
$$
a+c=0,\quad 2d+2b+ac=0,\quad bc+ad=2,\quad bd=15/16.
$$
The rest is yours (you need to solve a degree 3 equation of $a^2$, if there is no obvious rational root, then the problem is not interesting.).

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Lagrange resolvent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_by_Lagrange_resolvent) method, the characteristic polynomial is

$$s^6-\frac{15}{16}s^2-\frac14,$$
having the real root

$$s=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{61}i}{64}+\frac18}+\sqrt[3]{-\frac{\sqrt{61}i}{64}+\frac18}}.$$

Hence the factorization

$$4(x^2+sx+\frac{s^2}2-\frac1{4s})(x^2-sx+\frac{s^2}2+\frac1{4s}).$$